# Laravel Question: Is that possible to temporary disable url in route without remove?

Tags: php, laravel

Let say below this example:-

```
                        <li class="menu"><a href="">About</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="{{ route('HERE') }}">--></a></li>  
                    </ul>
                </li>
```

Is that possible make this  to disable? like  or // ?? Any Ideas?

Comment: you want to comment the code?

Comment: yes...!! but I tried this <!--{{route('HERE')}}--> or {{//route('HERE')}} but is not worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In blade file you can comment codes with {{-- your code --}}

```
{{-- <li><a href="{{ route('HERE') }}">--></a></li> --}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a URL helper In laravel to disable

```
<li><a href='{!! route('HERE'); !!}'>--></a></li>
```

[reference](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-to-create-link-with-blade-templating)